# How to pass the current lat long values from one class to another activity in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am using googleAPIClient to get the current lat long values using Location. I am getting the values of both my current lat and long in a separate class. I need to pass these current lat and long values inside my MapsActivity ( GoogleMap Activity), Since I have already created the object for the another class, from which I need to get the values, I don't know how to pass the values to this activity from the class.

Here's what I have tried. This is the class which I have created to get the current lat long values:

CurrentValues.java:

```
public class CurrentValues  implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener { 

    private static final String TAG = CurrentValues.class.getSimpleName();
private Context context;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLocation;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2 * 1000;  /* 10 secs */
    private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 2000; /* 2 sec */






    public CurrentValues( Context context){

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mLocationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        checkLocation();

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

        startLocationUpdates();

        mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if(mLocation == null){
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (mLocation != null) {

            // mLatitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mLocation.getLatitude()));
            //mLongitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mLocation.getLongitude()));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Location not Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection Suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Error: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());

    }








    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        String msg = "Updated Location: " +
                Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
                Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    }


    private boolean checkLocation() {
        if(!isLocationEnabled())
            showAlert();
        return isLocationEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }


    private boolean isLocationEnabled() {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager)context. getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
                mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }


    private void showAlert() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        dialog.setTitle("Enable Location")
                .setMessage("Your Locations Settings is set to 'Off'.\nPlease Enable Location to " +
                        "use this app")
                .setPositiveButton("Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        context.startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                    }
                });
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        // Create the location request
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        // Request location updates
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) context);
        Log.d("reque", "--->>>>");
    }



}
```

Now I need to pass the lat long values I got from this class to MapsActivity. Since I had already created object for the currentvalues class here in this activity, I don't know how to pass the value from there to here.

Here's my MapActivity (GoogleMap Activity)

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private CurrentValues currentValues;
    private Location location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

//        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
//        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
//        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
//
//        LatLng chennai = new LatLng(13.06,80);
//        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(chennai).title("Marker in Chennai"));
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 8f));

        // creating object for currentValues class

CurrentValues currentValues = new CurrentValues(this);

    }
}
```

I don't know how to proceed after this to pass the lat long values here. How can I proceed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2091465/7666442

Comment: make a bundle with the data and send the data to the activity with an intent containing the bundle as an extra.

Comment: you can not pass bundle from a java class to an activity.

Comment: You have to use Interface to send data.

Comment: Either use Interface to send data back to Activity or implement CurrentValues class as Observable